# Is java swing works with java 9+ and whats about netbeans support

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Oracle announce that, javafx will not package with java 11. Whats about java swing.

Netbeans try to introduce Apache Netbeans IDE 9 which will work jdk 9+. Can i work its palette that help to drag and drop swing components. Please Help to make decision.

Currently i am working a big project completely designed with swing. And its already in market.

Comment: Oracle did not said that it will not support JavaFX. It said JavaFX will not be shipped with the JDK. The same did happen with many other library, like the Java EE APIs (EG: JAXB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Java 11 includes Swing. See the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/package-summary.html

Comment: Whats about ide.

Comment: I don't know about NetBeans 9 but IntelliJ Idea does support Swing drag-and-drop.